# PRESTASHOP 1.7 Delete .html and category from URL

Tags: php, url, prestashop

How to delete .html and category from URL?

NOW: {category:/}{id}{-:id_product_attribute}-{rewrite}{-:ean13}.html

I need: {id}{-:id_product_attribute}-{rewrite}{-:ean13}

Presta 1.7
PHP 7.2

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Shop Parameters -> SEO & URLS and "Schema of URLs" tab. Remove the .html from the " Route to products" input

Change this:

> {category:/}{id}{-:id_product_attribute}-{rewrite}{-:ean13}.html

to this:

> {category:/}{id}{-:id_product_attribute}-{rewrite}{-:ean13}

And regenerate the .htaccess file

1. Rename the old .htaccess file (dont delete)
2. Disable Friendly URL -> save
3. Enable Friendly URL -> save

Comment: What about the category? When i delete it, it doesn't find products, 404 error